# Should developers do things that defeat strong-typing, kill intellisense and make it difficult for other developers to follow?

Tags: c#, development-process, self-improvement

Just to clarify: This is not a rant. I'm genuinely curious and it's a genuine question our of straight curiosity. I want to become a better developer and even little details like this count.

So, don't get me wrong, this is not a technical question about what a `Dictionary<string, string>` does. It's a question about when to use it as a developer in a team.

The reason for this is something that happened today at work. I started working on  a project made by another developer. He's still in the team so I can ask for info etc. BUT:

He uses dictionaries in C# for EVERYTHING. We do payments and he gets a known response from a payment gateway API.

The fields are known, so if it was me, I'd make an entity/model whatever you want to call it and then assign the values there and then save to the database (that was the short story). Have in mind that this is data that we need saved, but just for historical reasons. We're not actually doing any operations on it.

It's a big entity (as in, lots of fields). So I tried working on the project and it was impossible of course to get intellisense on it. I needed a single key to return the value to the frontend. Of course, I couldn't find it. It was nowhere in the projects (we have a monolith).

I had to spend about half an hour going through projects, commits, history, then the database and then I ended up asking him what happened to it, because I couldn't find it.

It was something really simple like `object.VariableInObject.Data["theKeyIwantFromTheDb"]` but actually looking for it was a nightmare. I got frustrated but I asked a very polite question about 'Why do you use Dictionaries so much? Especially if the data is known.'

His response was 'because I don't believe we should use objects for data we will keep for historical reasons only' (namely in this case history of a person's payments').

I don't know if that's valid. Is it? Because it was a nightmare to track down the data on a huge solution I hadn't worked on before. If it was in the project and not a dictionary I would have immediately found it.

So, the question is in the title. Development wise in a team, when other people use your solution and need to work on it, should you use something like that, that's hard to track down?

I'm asking because I personally try to make it easier for other developers and it seems like he's experienced (senior while I'm mid) and just doesn't give a...you know. He just does what he pleases (at least that's what it looks like).

P.S. If that plays a role, the db is Nosql.

Comment: Can someone explain why I'm getting downvoted please?

Comment: No, using dictionaries for well structured data is lazy garbage.

Comment: @Telastyn Would you mind elaborating in an answer please? I still don't understand why I'm getting downvoted massively by the way

Comment: Perhaps in a bit? I have a few meetings so don't have the time to provide a solid answer to this. I am not sure about the downvotes, though in general this has a few smells that can lead to them (being more of a rant than a question, lack of context making it very broad)

Comment: @Telastyn Thanks. Take your time. I appreciate the info. Didn't mean it to be a rant, I am genuinely curious. Thanks again, man.

Comment: Only reason I can think of that maps would be used for something like this is if they want to capture any new fields that are sent back with the response without having to do additional coding.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I thought so too but the fields coming back are set. They are provided by the payment gateway in their documentation they're not unknown. Also, what do you think about his response?

Comment: @Jabberwocky The fields can always be added to, so you can't be absolutely sure nothing will be added by the payment processor.  For his response, I don't see what maps vs predefined structures have to do with it, unless he's worried about possible added fields that would not be captured for historical reasons.  If there was that much concern for keeping a history of responses, the raw response from the payment processor should probably be kept/archived somewhere.

Comment: Nosql databases are essentially key/value stores.  Maybe that informs his mindset.  I don't see this ever happening in a "real" (i.e. relational) database, where structured data is the norm.  In any case, this is not the first time I've seen developers do something that makes things easy for themselves while making it difficult for everyone else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I get what you mean but for example the SQL API in Cosmos DB, allows you to use your db as a relational database (even if it's actually sql). So why not use dictionaries for everything and just ditch strongly typed objects forever if everything is a key/value pair?

Comment: I think you already know the answer to that.

Comment: Note of course that the "remote api might add some new fields" argument is somewhat irrelevant if the parser at the local end can discard those fields rather than choke on them (like an xml parser would if it was expecting elements in order) - remote end can add all the fields it wants but if the local code is written to only use a subset it will carry on working. Only time local code changes are needed is if a vital field is removed or if one of the new fields is useful and shall be relied upon.

Comment: All this said, if the remote is returning AccountNumber you can ctrl-f your project for it, find how it gets into the local model and work from there. If it's put into the dictionary as `dict["AccID"] = response.Get("AccountNumber")` and then accid is used everywhere that's a bit more of a nuisance but realistically that could be done with a strongly typed object too.. so without a strong example of why you found it so hard to grok this code I'm not completely sure what to say. Ctrl-f will still work even if Find All References doesn't and ctrl-f for ["AccID"] should return fewer garbage hits

Comment: @CaiusJard Because it wasn't going in as anything. it was being returned as a response and immediately written in the db. As in, all of the dictionary was being chucked in the db without being anywhere in the code to Ctrl+F it. Unfortunately

Comment: But then how do you consume it? How do you use this data, if none of the code ever tries to pull any of it out and store it anywhere in memory under some reference? Seems to me it's a valid case to reeive a bunch of key value pairs from a service, load them into a dictionary and store the dictionary in the db (assuming there is some code already that knows how to store a dictionary in a DB) - but that's just storage; surely somewhere along the line something in the code is going to have to take the account number out of the DB and use it, so there must be some "account number" ref in the code